# What is the equivalent mysql statement of criteria code shown below

Tags: hibernate, createcriteria

Im tryingto understand the code shown below

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Payables.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyId", companyId));

        criteria.createAlias("makePayment", "makePayment");

        if (creditorId != null) {
            criteria.createAlias("makePayment.creditor", "creditor");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("creditor.id", creditorId));
        }

            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("journalEntryId", journalEntryId));
```

I do know what createCriteria do, but adding createAlias makes it really confusing for me. I've already read the documentations but everything's still a blur.

Could you tell me how does the code above looks like using mysql statement?

Comment: enable sql logging when you run this query and you will see in log the full sql query

Comment: @FredericHenri unfortunately, I cannot do that but Its to long of a story to tell. Based here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html it is  making an innerjoin, if thats the case, then, where can I see this part "FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name" , the columns that they used to join the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Payables.class);
    // select * from Payables p;

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyId", companyId));
    // where p.companyId = :companyId

    criteria.createAlias("makePayment", "makePayment");
    // inner join Payement makePayment on makePayement.payables_id = p.id

    if (creditorId != null) {
        criteria.createAlias("makePayment.creditor", "creditor");
        // inner join Creditor c on c.payement_id = makePayement.id
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("creditor.id", creditorId));
        // where c.id = :creditorId
    }

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("journalEntryId", journalEntryId));
    // where p.journalEntryId = :journalEntryId
```

So the result is :

```
    select * from Payables p
    inner join Payement makePayment on makePayement.payables_id = p.id
    inner join Creditor c on c.payement_id = makePayement.id
    where p.companyId = :companyId
    and c.id = :creditorId
    and p.journal_entry_id = :journalEntryId
```

For the table name, use the value in @Table annotation of the entity, for the column name, use the @Column name value located on field or getter, for the column name used in join, use the value in the @JoinColumn annotation located near the @OneToMany or @ManyToOne annotation

Comment: Hi @Thierry May I ask where you get this "Payment" ? Thank you :)

Comment: you're creating an alias on the criteria "criteria.createAlias("makePayment", "makePayment");". In the entity Payables you should have a Collection field named makePayement. I just guessed a name. Without your entities mappings, it is not possible to write the exact sql table/column names ;)

Answer (score 0):

`createAlias` adds join

something like

```
...
FROM Payables p1
     JOIN Payment as p2 ON p2.paybles_id=p1.id
...
```

Then you can use the joined table to add conditions in WHERE section

Comment: from the code that I posted. Its unclear to me the  column that it used to join. Could you tell where that is? Thank you